# Automatically start/stop Existing Azure VM as build agent in VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm able to register my existing Azure VM as build agent in VSTS. Build works fine but I would like to turn the machine on and off only if there is any work for it. Is there any way how I can turn on the VM if I see there is some work for it in a queue and then turn it off if the queue is idle for let's say 5 minutes?

Answer (score 6):

Add a hosted agent job to the start to start the VM and add an agent job or additional step to the end to shut down the VM when finished.

Add an Agent job to run this as hosted to start the VM. Then use all build steps as self-hosted(private).

[image]

Add your Azure subscription

Choose Inline Script to add the following to start it with VM name and resource group

```
start-AzureRmVM -Name ""-ResourceGroupName ""
```

Add another Agent Job or additional step as the last Step
To shut down the VM when the build has finished.
With the following Script

```
stop-AzureRmVM -Name ""-ResourceGroupName "" -Force
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm wondering if this could be helpful for you because this is not exactly what you asked for. I used REST API calls before the build and after the build to start and then stop a specific VM. See how to [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/start) and [power off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/poweroff) a VM in the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines).

I created an agentless job as the first step, with a task entitled *Invoke REST API*. The task lets you authenticate to your Azure account, so you don't have to handle that manually. All you have to do is specify the URL suffix. For instance, to start a VM named MyVm, you add a suffix similar to the following one:

> /subscriptions/***subscription-id***/resourceGroups/***resource-group-name***/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/***MyVm***/**start**?api-version=2018-06-01

where the subscription ID and resource group can be verified in the Overview page of your virtual machine in Azure.

After the build you can add another agentless job, but this time with a REST call of the *powerOff* endpoint:

> /subscriptions/***subscription-id***/resourceGroups/***resource-group-name***/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/***MyVm***/**powerOff**?api-version=2018-06-01

Comment: Also, you might want to use the "Deallocate" endpoint instead of the "PowerOff" endpoint if you're wanting to minimize compute costs.

Comment: Struggled a bit with the authentication at first.  The key is, when setting up the REST api task, be sure to select a `Connection Type` of `Azure Resource Manager`

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t the good way to start/stop azure VM when build in VSTS. Regarding WebHook, there isn’t the event for queue build, for other events, they aren’t meet many requirements (e.g. non-CI build, queue build manually)

I recommend you use Hosted agent, with free Hosted Pipeline, you get 4 hours (240 minutes) per month and maximum duration of 30 minutes per build or deployment in Team Services.

[How to buy more pipeline capacity for builds and releases in Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/buy-more-build-vs)

Workaround:

1. Queue build at the specify time, for example, 7:00 am on Monday and Thursday, then you can auto-start and auto-shutdown the VM
2. Run on Hosted agent (Execute Powershell to start VM)=> Run on private agent

More information, you can refer to: [How to Create a Monster Build Agent in Azure for Cheap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/peterhauge/2016/08/14/how-to-create-a-monster-build-agent-in-azure-for-cheap/)

Comment: Isn't hosted pipeline be quite limited? For example, it does not support Xamarin iOS build or I cannot use local SQL Server Developer for quick integration tests [through snapshots]. In addition, at the moment afaik it only  supports VS 2017 15.1, while there is 15.3.3 already out, doesn't it?

Comment: @milanio Yes, there are some limits per to the environment of Hosted agent. So there is private build agent, but auto start/stop the agent machine is not supported.

Comment: thanks @starain-MSFT! Do you think it will be supported in the near future? What about this approach: hosted pipeline starts VM and then VM monitors queue and if it sees it's empty for some time it turn itself off [WebHook]. What do you think?

Comment: @milanio Not know how the Hosted agent work. There is the workaround that you can check. (updated my answer)

Comment: Vote up this suggestion https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365870/event-for-build-started.html if you'd like to see 'Build queued/build started' webhooks that would facilitate this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [WebHook](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/webhooks) in VSTS, and select the most appropriate event (like code pushed, or release created). Open the admin page for the team project in Visual Studio Team Services, and on the Service Hooks tab, run the subscription wizard, select the event you're interested in, and fill in the relevant criteria.

You could then use an [Azure Automation Runbook to subscribe to the WebHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) and, using [PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/start-stop-restart-and-delete-vms-in-microsoft-azure-with-powershell/), either use the build VM if it's already started or else start it up. You could use another WebHook to signal that a build has been completed, or [poll VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) from the VM via its various APIs.

You might want to delay shutting the VM down after a build, as there is a time cost associated with starting up / shutting down.

Comment: Hm, thank you, I'm using something similar to start&stop teamcity build agents and while it works I was hoping to avoid it in the VSTS. Beside with TeamCity you have to monitor build queue yourself and it seems you have to do the same in VSTS [see @starain-MSFT answer]